# Find the operator norm

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1& a \\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$ determines. Find the operator norm $||T||$ with respect to the norm $|(u, v)| = \max\{|u|, |v|\}$ in the domain and codomain.

Definition $||T||=\inf\{c\ge0:|T(x)|\le c|x|, \forall x\in V\}$ where $V$ is the domain of a linear mapping.

So in this case $||T||=\inf\{c\ge0: \left |\begin{pmatrix} 1& a \\ 0 &1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix}\right| \le c|(u,v)|, \forall (u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2\}$ or

$||T||=\inf\{c\ge0\: \left|\begin{pmatrix} u+av \\ v \end{pmatrix}\right| \le c\max\{|u|, |v|\}, \forall (u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2\}$

So I want to find the smallest such $c$ that satisfies this $\left |\begin{pmatrix} u+av \\ v \end{pmatrix}\right | \le c\max\{|u|, |v|\}$.

I must have made a mistake since I can not compare a number with a vector. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You missed the norm around $T(x)$

Comment: I must have missed that in my notes, Thank you! Now I can compare apples to apples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, in your inequality you want
$$\max\{|u+av|,|v|\}\le c\max\{|u|,|v|\}.$$
Then you must just work by cases. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can, 4 cases I believe. Thank you

Comment: @Burgundy Actually, I think you also have to consider $a>0$, $a=0$ and $a<0$. But probably you can just treat a couple of cases and then reduce the others to those already solved ;)

Comment: I can look at the case in which $a=0$. Then $\max\{|u|,|v|\}\le c \max\{|u|,|v|\}$ for all non negative $c$. So then $||T||=0$. This makes sense to me, but the other answer says otherwise.

Comment: @Burgundy Yeah, because the constant $c$ you can put there is $1$, not $0$, so in the case $a=0$ you have $\|T\|=1$...

Comment: wow maybe I need some sleep and/or caffeine, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better to use the following definition for operator norm (which you can verify to be the same as the one you gave): $\Vert T\Vert=\sup\left\{\Vert Tx\Vert:\Vert x\Vert=1\right\}$.

For $x=(u,v)$, we have $Tx=(u+av,v)$, which has norm $\max(|u+av|,|v|)$, and this is always smaller than $\max(|u|+|a||v|,|v|)\leq\max(1+|a|,|1|)=1+|a|$. To maximize this, we can try to make $u$ and $av$ have the same sign and $|v|$ be maximum:

Thus, simply set $x=(1,sgn(a))$, where $sgn(a)=1$ if $a\geq 0$ and $sgn(a)=-1$ if $a<0$. With this, $sgn(a)a=|a|$. This way we obtain $|x|=1$ and $||Tx||=\max(|1+sgn(a)a|,|sgn(a)|)=\max(1+|a|,1)=1+|a|$. Therefore $||T||=1+|a|$.

Comment: At the beginning of the second paragraph you used an incorrect norm (he's taking the max on the elements, not the $1$-norm...)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Thank you. Corrected it already.